# Manually changing the activations of stateful LSTM network (Keras)

Tags: neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

How does one change the activations in a Keras network ? (I am using LSTM)

I tried the following

```
 def getAllActivations(self):
    activations=[]
    for layer in self.nn.layers:
        activations.append(layer.output)
    return activations
def setAllActivations(self,activations):
    i=0
    for layer in self.nn.layers:
        layer.output=activations[i]
        i+=1
```

but using the line `layer.output=activations[i]` gives the error:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: You cannot change them, they are computed. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917662/online-stateful-lstm-which-alternatingly-trains-and-predicts-keras